# Cannot read data from smart Contract with web3 js

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs

Im having trouble reading data from a smart contract

I have following js script right here: (bcc-js.js)

```
var contract_address = "0x88e304D8638c31DaC3336917bbE4A152927198D8";
var contract_abi = '[{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalSupply","type":"uint256"}],"name":"LogRebase","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"_owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner_","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"supplyDelta","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rebase","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]';




window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            await ethereum.enable();
            var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            var option={from: accounts[0] };
            var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract_abi,contract_address);


            var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();


            //const agiAccountBalance = await agiContract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call();


            document.getElementById('totalSupply').innerHTML = supply;



            ethereum.on('accountsChanged', async (accounts) => {
              await ethereum.enable();
              var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts();
              var option={from: accounts[0] };
              var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,address);
              console.log(accounts[0]);



              var supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();

            })
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        // Acccounts always exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = "Use '<a href='https://metamask.io/' target='_blank' >Metamask</a>' on a Desktop or use <a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wallet.crypto.trustapp&hl=en' target='_blank'>TrustWallet</a>' on a mobile";

    }
});
I want to print out totalSupply on my UI (index.html)

 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="count-box">
              <i class="icofont-simple-smile"></i>
              <span data-toggle="counter-up"><p id="totalSupply">490</p></span>
              <p>Addresses</p>
            </div>
          </div>
When runing it i get this error

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at bcc-js.js:14

inpage.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
    at inpage.js:1
    at inpage.js:1
    at n (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at inpage.js:1
    at i (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
    at inpage.js:1
    at c (inpage.js:1)
    at inpage.js:1
```

What do I need to do to see the totalSupply on my UI?

the file js file is hooked up properly to my UI, I tested with another code snipped and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue may comes from line `var accounts= await web3.eth.getAccounts()`; It should be `var accounts= await window.web3.eth.getAccounts();` instead. In your code accounts[] is undefined, so `var option={from: accounts[0] };` throws an error. One more point, "option" is a javascript reserved keyword. Use "options" instead for instance.